# Ask a question about double sum series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to compute $\Sigma_{i=1}^n \Sigma_{j=1}^i \frac{D_j}{n-j+1}$, every $D_j >0$.

The above is equal to $\Sigma_{j=1}^n \Sigma_{i=j}^n \frac{D_j}{n-j+1}$. I am asking how to see this quickly.

Comment: Note the indices imply that $1 \le j \le i \le n$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{\{j \leqslant i\}}=\begin{cases}1, & j \leqslant i\\0,&j>i \end{cases}$ to get common upper summation limits and switch the order of summation :

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \frac{D_j}{n-j+1}=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{D_j}{n-j+1}\mathbb{1}_{\{j \leqslant i\}}= \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{D_j}{n-j+1}\mathbb{1}_{\{j \leqslant i\}}= \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=j}^n  \frac{D_j}{n-j+1}$$

Comment: When can we safely switch the Sigma?

Comment: @Jackie: With finite sums it is always safe to switch.  With infinite sums it is permissible under certain conditions -- for example, if the terms are nonnegative or if the series is absolutely convergent, etc .